# How to resolve Pandas pd.Cut having Error / Bug?

Tags: python, pandas

I need the `pandas` `pd.Cut` function for getting range of given series based on `bins`:

But when my `bins` size increases beyond **`101`** it gives me Error as:

```
 Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Example:

```
pd.cut(x=pd.Series(range(100)), bins=pd.Series(range(101))) 
>0              NaN
1       (0.0, 1.0]
2       (1.0, 2.0]
3       (2.0, 3.0]
```

Error generating Example:

```
pd.cut(x=pd.Series(range(100)), bins=pd.Series(range(102))) 
>TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

What should i do? [image: Error pic]

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. The code is running fine on my system. Categories (101, interval[int64]): [(0, 1] < (1, 2] < (2, 3] < (3, 4] ... (97, 98] < (98, 99] <
                                    (99, 100] < (100, 101]]

Comment: upto 101 no problem try with 102+

Comment: I have tested with 102 and 200.

Comment: which python and pandas version u have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i resolved my problem. By installing `Python 64bit`. now no problem.
Previously it have `32 bit python`. My system is `windows 10 64bit`.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I have run into the same problem. I discovered this when I ran a programme I'd written on my home 64-bit machine (running 64-bit python) on my work 32-bit Windows machine (with 32 bit python).
I am able to replicate your error exactly using the code you provided (including the cut-off point between 101 and 102).
Switching to 64-bit is not an option for me here as I am restricted by hardware. I would be interested if anyone figures out a work around to this problem!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30736718)